# for image pattern recognization what to use OpenCV or Java

Tags: java, android, image-processing

I want to recognize an image using camera in android, I just want to know is there any better solution rather than using open-cv, I have done it using open-cv but as using native code on Android generally does not result in a noticable performance improvement, but it always increases your app complexity. In general, you should only use the NDK if it is essential. so is there any option to achieve it in Java. need your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to write C++ code, you don't have to. OpenCV for Android provides Java libraries and a pretty thorough API. 
Check http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/android_binary_package.html

You also have the option of writing or re-using C++ code.